# bash script - print X rows from a seleccted file from a folder

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a script which help to follows the logs of my application.

The logs of my application are written to "var/log/MyLogs/" with the following pattern:

```
runningNumber_XXX.txt , for example:
0_XXX.txt
37_xxx.txt
99_xxx.txt
101_xxx.txt
103_xxx.txt
```

I'm trying to write a bash script (without a success for now) which will print last 20 rows of the last log file (the last log file is the file with has the biggest prefix number).

I know I need to go over the files in the folder (for file in /var/log/MyLogs/*) and check which file name has the biggest prefix, and after it print the last 20 rows from the selected file.

please help me....

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

```
find /var/log/MyLogs -iname '*_xxx.txt' | sort -n | tail -1 | xargs tail -20
```

- Get correct files
- Sort numerically
- Get last log file
- Get last 20 rows

Comment: thanks (but if I have: 99_xxx.txt and 103_xxx.txt it give me the content of 99_xxx.txt)...

Comment: @user3668129 The `-n` flag to `sort` makes it treat the sort key as a number, rather than a string.

Comment: Technically this solution isn't 100% correct. Filenames may contain not only spaces (which is the main reason for your discussion with @Vijay) but also those "weird symbols", including '\n'. So the _correct_ solution would imply `find .... -print0` and subsequent "dances" with handling '\0' in the output stream (`xargs -0` would help in certain situations but no `sort`, no `tail` etc). But as @Vijay reasonably said log filenames usually don't contain any "bad symbols" so all these precautions are excessive in this particular case. Although I won't downvote your soultion, it's nice.

Answer (score 1):

`tail -20 $(ls -1 /var/log/MyLogs/*_*.txt | sort -n -t _ -k 1 -r | head -1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 [0-9]*_XXX.txt | sort -rn | head -1 | xargs tail -20
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually is the bad practice using `ls` in shell scripts, but if you can ensure than the logfiles doesn't contains *spaces* and other strange characters, you can use a simple:

```
tail -20 $(ls -t1 /var/log/[0-9]*_XXX.txt | head -1)
```

The:

- `ls -t` sorts the files my modification time newest comes first
- `head` the the 1st
- `tail` print the last lines

AGAIN, this is usually a bad practice, you can use it only when you knows what you're doing.